# Flutter element not appearing when in for loop

Tags: flutter, for-loop, dart, aws-amplify

I'm trying to make an UI-element for every element in a list of recordings, but nothing is appearing. I've made a class which asks for the Name, Date and Description, which i'm providing for each element in the list.

The one I'm making outside of the for loop, to test if it will draw anything, is showing up as intended. I also know that the list does contain the elements it needs.

The elements in the list is loaded from an Amplify DataStore instance, and is printing correctly to the Debug console.

Here's the code:

```
class BuildRecordingsList extends StatefulWidget {
  const BuildRecordingsList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BuildRecordingsListState createState() => _BuildRecordingsListState();
}

class _BuildRecordingsListState extends State<BuildRecordingsList> {
  List<Recording> recordings = DataStoreAppProvider().recordings;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DataStoreAppProvider().getRecordings();
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          RecordingElement(
              recordingName: 'recordingName',
              recordingDate: TemporalDate.now(),
              recordingDescription: 'recordingDescription'),
          for (var rec in recordings)
            RecordingElement(
              recordingName: '${rec.name}',
              recordingDate: rec.date,
              recordingDescription: '${rec.description}',
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm still very new to Flutter and Dart, so please do tell me if you'll need more info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for doesn't return anything and there is not the proper place to return things from for.

You shall checkout the Iterable methods: forEach, map, etc...

In this case you have to use the map method, which takes an array and returns another after processing every element.

[1, 2, 3].map((index) => index.toString()) // ["1", "2", "3"]

In this case, you have to take every element and return a Widget that uses your value.

```
...recordings.map((rec) {
  return RecordingElement(
    recordingName: '${rec.name}',
    recordingDate: rec.date,
    recordingDescription: '${rec.description}',
  );
})
```

As your Column children accept a List as value, you have to destructure your elements.

DESTRUCTURING:

List firstList = [1, 2];

List secondList = [0, ...firstList]; // [0, 1, 2]

THE ENTIRE CODE:

```
class BuildRecordingsList extends StatefulWidget {
  const BuildRecordingsList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BuildRecordingsListState createState() => _BuildRecordingsListState();
}

class _BuildRecordingsListState extends State<BuildRecordingsList> {
  List<Recording> recordings = DataStoreAppProvider().recordings;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DataStoreAppProvider().getRecordings();
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          RecordingElement(
              recordingName: 'recordingName',
              recordingDate: TemporalDate.now(),
              recordingDescription: 'recordingDescription'),
          ...recordings.map((rec) {
            return RecordingElement(
            recordingName: '${rec.name}',
            recordingDate: rec.date,
            recordingDescription: '${rec.description}',
            );
          })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't really understand where I should map the list and what the destructuring does, why I need to destructure it, and how i'm going to use the destructured list.

Comment: I put in the bottom the entire code with the mapping. You have an example of destructuring above the entire code. It can be used to destructure Maps and Arrays in others, like in the upper case. If you want to understand more about destructuring, you can check this video out, it is about JavaScript destructuring, but it is the same in Dart. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIq3qLaHCIs

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the video, but unfortunately this still doesn't show any create any RecordingElement widgets.

Comment: Okay, so i've just fixed the problem, and it was earlier in the code with defining the List variable.

Comment: I see, I'm pleased to hear that you solved it :)